# Twig_Error_Runtime ; the "core" extension is not enabled ; symfony

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I've inherited a Symfony/PHP web app codebase with zero documentation. I'm a nodejs dev so you can image the fun...! Anyway I'm getting there, my focus atm is to be able to run the project locally.

Here's the Symfony version:

```
Symfony version 2.7.16 - app/dev/debug
```

I've installed packages via `composer install`.

I can start the web app locally via CLI:

```
php app/console server:run

Server running on http://127.0.0.1:8000
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

However when I try to access this URL I'm seeing the following error in browser. Have google'd around but couldn't work it out so am hoping someone here can point me in the right direction.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is due to trying to run a new version of twig on an old version of Symfony

as you can see here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20284

They mention something similar, perhaps try to include an older version of twig in composer?

```
composer require twig/twig 1.23
```